# How to provide non-table parameters in delete procedure mvc EF database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters

I am using view and stored procedures as a layer between code and database.
All of the create, update, delete procedure need to be passed a *User Id* and a *Transaction Id* so as to manage security and history keeping.

In the update procedures, I have successfully received the OLD user id and *transaction ids* from the view, replaced the record values with new ones, and called the *SP* to save.

the problem is the Delete SP. Again, I am trying to update the values in the record before invoking the db.Remove and Save methods. Unfortunately, the delete SP is called with the old values, not the new ones.

I am considering calling the SP directly, but am a little scared of what Changes I might have to make in the db context to keep everything in sync, and not have the next Save Changes try to do the deletion again. I would prefer to work in with the existing EF mechanism if possible.
Perhaps I just need to know where in the complexity of the db context the ortigianl values are stored so I can update them.

Code wise, a more normal system would simply have one SP parameter - the ID of the record to delete. Perhaps two for concurrency control - ID and timestamp, but both of these are selected from the databse in the first place. How can I get other parameters into a more complex SP?

As a more general expression of the problem, How can I add extra parameters that do not come from the database, to the call list of an EF Delete SP?

Comment: It's very hard (impossible) to piece together what this is about, please supply a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).